# Internal product of rings is homomorphic image of direct product

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a ring (commutative with $1$) and $A,B \subseteq R$ subrings (both still having the same $1$). Then we can consider the outer direct product of the rings $A \times B$ with elementwise addition/multiplication. We can also consider the inner product
$$ AB= \{ \sum_{i=0}^n a_i b_i \; | \; n \in \mathbb{N}, a_i \in A ,b_i \in B  \} \subseteq R $$
with addition/multiplication in $R$ (which is the smallest subring of $R$ containing both $A$ and $B$).

Is the ring $AB$ a homomorphic image of the ring $A \times B$? Is it true and if so, is there a reference for ist? If it is not true, what counterexample do we have?

If $A \subseteq B$ this is the case as $\phi \colon A\times B \to AB=B,(a,b) \mapsto b$ is an epimorphism. But what about the general case? The obvious map $(a,b) \mapsto ab$ is not a ring-homomorphism and I could not find any other map which would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there exists $f\colon A\times B\to AB$; then $f(1,1)=1$; set $x=f(1,0)$ and $y=f(0,1)$. Then $xy=f(1,0)f(0,1)=f(0,0)=0$, but also $x+y=1$,  $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$.

Take your favorite ring with no nontrivial idempotents (a field, for instance) and having at least two distinct subrings.

Comment: Thanks! However, I do not see the contradiction yet. Let e.g. $R=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, $A=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),B=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. Then from your computations we must have $x=0$ and $y=1$ (or vice versa), so e.g. we have $f(a,b)=f(0,b)$ for all $a,b$. Do we get a contradiction with the surjectivity of $f$?

Comment: @blablablup Since $xy=0$, one has $x=0,y=1$ or $x=1,y=0$. Try with the first and see.

Comment: Thanks! I think, I got it now: As $m f(0,n/m)=mnf(0,1/m)=nf(0,1)=n$ (since $f$ is a ring-homomorphism) we have $f(0,q)=q$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Also $f(0,\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3}$ as $f(0,\sqrt{3}) f(0,\sqrt{3}) = 3$. Then $f(a,b)=f(0,b)=f(0,b_1+b_2 \sqrt{3})=f(0,b_1)+f(0,b_2)f(0,\sqrt{3}) \in B$ for $b_1,b_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be in the image of $f$, so $f$ cannot be surjective. However, I would expect, that you had a different argument in mind...